# I am learning C# I want to put in a int but cant figure how to convert it

Tags: c#

I want the user to be able to enter the number at the menu however when I do this it says its a string being enter. I have tried to convert as I left the code in but it will not work.

```
namespace Day1.Day1.Exercises
{
    class PasswordGenerator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int MainMenu = 0;

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("                        PASSWORD GENERATOR");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("1 - Generate Password");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Help");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Exit");

            MainMenu = Console.ReadLine();

            int input = Convert.ToInt16(MainMenu);

            if (input == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Generating your password");
            }
            else if (input == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("                        HELP");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number allocated on screen to an option");

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the length of your password you wish it to be ");

                Console.WriteLine("Wait for your password to be generated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainMenu` should probably be a `string`. Tip: When you post a question that involves an error message it helps to include the exact message text and to indicate what line of your code the error applies to. And redact the code down to what is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try googling "C# Int32.Parse" and the results should be able to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the MainMenu variable with the result of Console.ReadLine

```
...
var MainMenu = Console.ReadLine();
int input = int.Parse(MainMenu);
...
```

Comment: MainMenu is already an int. It should be declared as a string.

Comment: -1 The OP is already converting MainMenu. The problem is MainMenu's type.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer int.TryParse() because Console.ReadLine() could return an empty string as well. In this case int.Parse(string) will throw an exception.

```
bool valid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out MainMenu);
```